# How to reference the type of a property?

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a type `Projection<T>` that describes an object whose properties can only be a `number` (0 or 1) or a Projection of the type of that attribute.

Example:

Given types:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  address: Address
}

interface Address {
  street: string;
  country: string;
}
```

The `Projection<Person>` would be:

```
const p: Projection<Person> = { // this is a Projection<Person>
  name: 1,
  address: { // this is a Projection<Address>
    street: 0,
    country: 1
  }
}
```

Is that possible at all in typescript? I am getting stuck in the recursive Projection part

```
export type Projection<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: number | Projection<???> };
```

Using `number | Projection<any>` works, but of course does not check if the fields declared belong to `Address`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is

```
type Projection<T> = { [K in keyof T]: number | Projection<T[K]> };
```

Also, if the fields in your original structure are always strings, you can make it more specific by writing:

```
type Projection<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? number : Projection<T[K]> };
```

And if the fields are not always string, you may try:

```
type Projection<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? Projection<T[K]> : number };
```

Comment: it won't always be string.. it can be any other type

Comment: @DouglasCVasconcelos How about now?